# disable is true, but I can edit field

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

here my controller:

```
  @RequestMapping("category/view/{id}")
    public String viewCategory(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        Optional<Category> category = categoryRepository.findById(id);
        logger.info("find_category = " + category);
        model.addAttribute("isDisable", true);
        model.addAttribute("category", category);
        return "category";
    }
```

here template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Category template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3 th:if="*{isDisable}">Disabled</h3>
    <h3 th:if="*{isAdd}">Add category</h3>
    <h3 th:unless="*{isAdd}">Edit category</h3>
    <form method="post" action="#" th:object="${category}" th:action="@{/category}">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" th:field="*{name}" th:disable="${isDisable}"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="created" th:field="*{created}"/>
        <textarea placeholder="Description" rows="5" id="description"
                  th:field="*{description}"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here generated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/public/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Disabled</h3>

    <h3>Edit category</h3>
    <form method="post" action="/category"><input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="4fc8f3e0-f5f4-4da1-858c-fe0a9d05cdfb"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="1"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" disable="true" name="name" value="Toys"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="created" name="created" value="08.01.2020 18:52:07"/>
        <textarea placeholder="Description" rows="5" id="description" name="description">Toys&#39;s description</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the **disable="true"**:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" disable="true" name="name" value="Toys"/>
```

but I can edit field **Name**

Why?

Answer (score 4):

It is not an disable = true, it's just disabled.

```
<input type="text" disabled>
```